# UPDATE two rows - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update two rows in my database using a query (which is going to be run from a PHP script) and there is just one Condition (WHERE). What I've tried is:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE ' . CANNED_MESSAGES . "
                SET canned_message_content = '" . $db->sql_escape($content) . "', 
                    canned_message_title = '" . $db->sql_escape($title) . "'
                WHERE id = '" . intval($id) . "'" ;
$db->sql_query($sql);
```

Can you tell me whats wrong with my query? :)

Comment: Can you tell us why you think that there is something wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us what went wrong when you tried to execute the query? :-)

Comment: Seems to me like the `id` is likely to be unique to one row. Why do you think that this should update two?

Comment: What error are you seeing? Or is it not updating as much as you'd hope?

Comment: print `$sql` before you execute it. And what error are you getting?

Comment: I get no error, it simply wont update the stuff in my table :(.

Comment: Well that likely means your where clause isn't finding any rows to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to Quotes mismatch. Please use this

```
$sql = "UPDATE '" . CANNED_MESSAGES ."'
                SET canned_message_content = '" . $db->sql_escape($content) . "', 
                    canned_message_title = '" . $db->sql_escape($title) . "'
                WHERE id = '" . intval($id) . "' " ;
```

Comment: How can anyone vote down the answer without considering the little things in programming. The little most thing in programming can create the issue as it did.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that two rows can have the same id column. Do they? If not, how could you update 2 rows by specifying a condition on a column with such a constraint?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you please explain? :)

Comment: Okay, here, I'll try to explain:

that query is actually part of a function, and the ID is a hidden field in HTML, so every CANNED MESSAGE has its own ID, and in the function, for ID, I simply passed $_POST['id']. I cannot clarify it pretty well, I hardly understand how I got it to work lol :P